# Core 2.0 published to IIS, web.config error

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, iis-10

Using Visual Studio 2019 I've published my Core 2.0 website.

I can run the website without error from command-line:

```
c:\www>dotnet My.Site.Web.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: c:\www
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I can load the site without issue in a browser using port 5000.

I've also created an IIS site that points to c:\www. The Application Pool is using "No managed code".

I have the following installed:

- Microsoft .NET Core 2.1.13 - Windows Server Hosting
- Microsoft .NET Core Runtime 2.1.13 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Core Runtime 2.1.13 (x86)
- Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.0.100 (x64) from Visual Studio

If I try to open the IIS site I get error, "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. Config File \?\C:\www\web.config"

The "Config Source" it says is "-1:
0:"

The hosting bundle was re-installed just minutes ago.

In IIS manager when I open the website and double click the "ASP" widget I get error:

"There was an error while performing this operation.
Details:
Filename \?\C:\www\web.config
Error:"

I have a second development machine with the same website, same paths, Core runtime and SDK, and the website works on that machine. I copied the working site to the machine with the site which doesn't run, and it still doesn't fix the issue.

It seems to be acting like the IIS hosting bundle isn't installed, but I installed it minutes ago.

My web.config is as generated by Visual Studio, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>

      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>

      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\My.Site.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Any error message? Maybe you can refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I quoted the error in my post. It's not very helpful. I did answer my own question though. And no, that post doesn't help. Thank you though.

Comment: 500 internal error is generic issue. Please check the full error message on the server.

Comment: The IIS log gives no further details.

Comment: Difficult if you don't know further error. I follow tutorial above and I can publish without any issues. One thing again, make sure that your application pool set to no managed code.

Answer (score 0):

Despite already have .NET Core Runtime 2.1.13 installed, I just installed .NET Core Runtime 3.0.0 and it has solved the issue.

When I run `dotnet --info` I saw this in part:

```
Runtime Environment:
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\
```

So I took a guess that it wanted to use a 3.0 run-time for some reason, and installed that. It seems to have worked.